# How to get the executable extension across platforms in Rust?

Tags: windows, path, rust, filenames

I'm writing portable Rust code to look for a program in some directories.  On Windows I expect it will be `foo.exe` and elsewhere just `foo`.

Obviously I could just use `if cfg!(windows)` but that seems ugly.

Is there a better way to find the platform's executable file extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [`std::env::consts::EXE_SUFFIX`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/consts/) will be `.exe` on Windows, and [`std::env::consts::EXE_EXTENSION`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/consts/) will be `exe`.  Both are empty on Unix.

These can be combined with the base name using for example [`std::path::PathBuf::set_extension`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.set_extension).